# Replace textfield's keyboard on uipopover in UIwebview

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have HTML pages with `textfields` and after touch on any of this `textfield` in `UIWebView`, I need to show `UIPopOver` with the static information and hide a keyboard.
How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

set the textfield's `inputview` to nil.

```
textField.inputView = nil;
```

Comment: this textfield inside in UIwebview

Comment: you will have to add and observer with NSNotificationCenter for KeyBoardWillShow notification. then inside that method, you will have to try and get the keyboard from the window. Refer to this `http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6573-howto-customize-uikeyboard.html` . And replace the keyboard there. with your popover.

Comment: add a tapgestureRecognizer to the webview. Then whenever u tap on the webview. Get the touchpoint and keep it. Now if u follow the link that i have provided, u can see that the keyboard is a subview, remove it. and present ur popover from the touch point that u saved from the gestures selector. Try it this way.

Comment: i can't remove the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in you `viewDidLoad` method, it is notification that notify you when keyboard is display

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

Add you popup view in `UITextField` in  following method  of notification

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow
{
       if(self.myTextFieldName)
        {
          [myTextFieldName resignFirstResponder]; /// resignFirstResponder/hideKeyBoard when you click on UITextFiled 
          myTextFieldName.inputView = self.PopUpView. // and add your popup view as input view of yourTextFiled         
        }

}
```

Comment: how will this delegate method be called ??? the textfield is a part of  the HTML he is loading. as such he cant set its delegate, as such the following delegate method won't be called. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: instead of `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` it should be `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` i think. As with the former one, the keyboard will appear and then dismiss.

Comment: hm, problem is that i havent UItextfield, i have textfield in UIwebview and uitextfield's delegates doesn't work